# Синхронизация с использованием asynс/await

Tags: c#, многопоточность, async-await

Есть такой код (взят у Шилдта и немного упрощен).

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
class ThreadTest
{
    object lk = new object();
    public void Tick()
    {
        lock (lk)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < 12; x++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("tick");
                Thread.Sleep(200);
                Monitor.Pulse(lk);
                Monitor.Wait(lk);
            }
            Monitor.PulseAll(lk);
        }
    }

    public void Tock()
    {
        lock (lk)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < 12; x++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("tock");
                Thread.Sleep(200);
                Monitor.Pulse(lk);
                Monitor.Wait(lk);
            }
            Monitor.PulseAll(lk);
        }
    }
}
class demo
{
    static void Main()
    {
        ThreadTest thrTest = new ThreadTest();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(thrTest.Tick); t1.Start();
        Thread t2 = new Thread(thrTest.Tock); t2.Start();
    }
}
```

Этот код в разных потоках запускает методы и синхронизируя их работу выводит на консоль Тик или Так. Но вот задумался, а как можно такой же функционал реализовать, но используя `asynс/await` ? И реально ли это ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Да, можно, хотя это немного сложнее.

Вот в [этой статье](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/02/12/building-async-coordination-primitives-part-6-asynclock/) расписана механика того, как сделать это самостоятельно. Но лучше не изобретать велосипед, а воспользоваться готовой библиотекой [AsyncEx](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nito.AsyncEx/). С подключением этой библиотеки можно написать просто:

```
readonly AsyncLock mutex = new AsyncLock();
public async Task UseLockAsync()
{
    using (await mutex.LockAsync())
    {
        // тут вам принадлежит lock
    }
}
```

(Оба автора — признанные специалисты в асинхронном программировании. Stephen Toub — один из разработчиков [TPL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717(v=vs.110).aspx) в Microsoft, Stephen Cleary — автор хорошей книги [Concurrency in C# Cookbook](http://stephencleary.com/book/).)

---

По поводу конкретного кода с очерёдностью выполнения — такое можно сделать проще. Я использовал для синхронизации двух потоков `AsyncBarrier` из того же `Nito.AsyncEx`.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Program().Run().Wait();
    }

    async Task Run()
    {
        pingBarrier = new AsyncBarrier(2);
        pongBarrier = new AsyncBarrier(2);
        var ping = Ping();
        var pong = Pong();
        await ping;
        await pong;
    }

    AsyncBarrier pingBarrier, pongBarrier;

    async Task Ping()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
        {
            await pingBarrier.SignalAndWaitAsync();
            pingBarrier = new AsyncBarrier(2);
            Console.WriteLine($"ping #{i}, thread {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
            await pongBarrier.SignalAndWaitAsync();
        }
    }

    async Task Pong()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
        {
            await pingBarrier.SignalAndWaitAsync();
            await pongBarrier.SignalAndWaitAsync();
            pongBarrier = new AsyncBarrier(2);
            Console.WriteLine($"pong #{i}, thread {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
        }
    }
}
```

---

Заметьте, что первоначальный пример Шилдта неправилен. Он использует `Thread.Sleep` для того, чтобы «гарантировать» наличие ожидающего потока, что является грубым просчётом. Из [документации на `Monitor.Pulse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.pulse(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The `Monitor` class does not maintain state indicating that the `Pulse` method has been called. Thus, if you call `Pulse` when no threads are waiting, the next thread that calls `Wait` blocks as if `Pulse` had never been called. If two threads are using `Pulse` and `Wait` to interact, this could result in a deadlock.

Впрочем, Шилдт знаменит неаккуратностью в своих книгах.

---

Уточнение: нет, пример Шилдта всё же правилен, `Thread.Sleep` в нём не играет решающей роли. Тем не менее, приведённая цитата из MSDN всё ещё в силе, и использование `Wait`/`Pulse` для синхронизации потоков опасно.